# How to remove and add circles on the line chart dynamically?

Tags: highcharts

**How to remove and add circles on the line chart dynamically on button onclick?**

Answer (score 0):

You can hide svg elements (circles), by hide() function.

http://jsfiddle.net/HzUZg/1

```
 $('#btn').click(function(){

        $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

            if(data.graphic.visibility=="hidden")
                data.graphic.show();
            else
                data.graphic.hide();
        });

    });
```